# Batching operations in gremlin on Neptune

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

In AWS Neptune documentation ([best-practices-gremlin-java-batch-add](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/best-practices-gremlin-java-batch-add.html)) they recommend batching operations together.
How can I batch a few operations together in case one of them may end the stream.
For example if I want to batch together the following:

```
g.V(2).drop().addV('test').property(id,1)
```

The problem is that the addV won't be called.
Is there a way to batch the drop and the addV together and making sure the addV will be called?
I tried to put fold() in between but because it isn't supported natively in Neptune and will probably create performance issues.
The sideEffect isn't a good option for performance reasons with Neptune as well (see drop documentation in [gremlin-step-support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-step-support.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the `sideEffect()` step to perform the `drop()` as shown in [this recipe](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#operating-on-dropped-elements).  In your case this might look something like:

```
g.addV('test').property(id,1).sideEffect(V(2).drop())
```

Comment: Thank you @bechbd, but doing drop in sideEffect on Neptune isn't supported natively (added a link in the question) so I assumed it will provide bad performance?